# Drawing lines with canvas in pdf dart

Tags: pdf, dart, canvas

I'm using the plugin [dart-pdf](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf) to generate a pdf document. I need to add a checkbox, however, there is no Checkbox Widget, so I've been trying to draw it with canvas (something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m38gk.png) would be perfect). However, I'm not able to draw even a line. The following code does not draw anything:

```
canvas
..moveTo(0, size.y)
..lineTo(0,0)
..lineTo(size.x, size.y)
..setColor(PdfColors.blue);
```

Only if I call *fillPath*, it does draw a filled triangle:

```
canvas
..moveTo(0, size.y)
..lineTo(0,0)
..lineTo(size.x, size.y)
..setColor(PdfColors.blue)
..fillPath();
```

but that's not what I want to achieve.

Edit: In the end, I did it like this:

```
pw.CustomPaint pwCheckBox(bool checked){
if(!checked){
  return pw.CustomPaint(
    size: const PdfPoint(10, 10),
    painter: (PdfGraphics canvas, PdfPoint size) {
      canvas
        ..moveTo(0, 0)
        ..lineTo(0, size.y)
        ..lineTo(size.x, size.y)
        ..lineTo(size.x, 0)
        ..lineTo(0, 0)
        ..setColor(PdfColors.black)
        ..strokePath();
    },
  );
}
return pw.CustomPaint(
    size: const PdfPoint(10, 10),
painter: (PdfGraphics canvas, PdfPoint size) {
canvas
  ..moveTo(0, 0)
  ..lineTo(0, size.y)
  ..lineTo(size.x, size.y)
  ..lineTo(size.x, 0)
  ..lineTo(0, 0)
  ..moveTo(0, size.y/2)
  ..lineTo(size.x/3, 0)
  ..lineTo(size.x, size.y)
  ..setColor(PdfColors.black)
  ..strokePath();
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code fragment does not display anything because it only builds the path, it does not actually paint it on the canvas.
fillPath paints the path by filling it. strokePath paints the path by stroking it (this is what you need probably).